# How can I implement a RecyclerView with a different number of items by rows?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I know that I can implement a RecyclerView with different views for items on Android.

But my need is a little bit different here. I would like to know how can I implement a RecyclerView with a different number of items by rows.

For example, I would have 2 items for first row, then just 1 item for second row, then 3 items for third row, ...

Is it possible to implement this with a RecyclerView? If so, How can I implement it?

Thanks for your help.

Sylvain

Comment: Have all items the same structure? Or there are so different between them?

Comment: GridLayoutManager with spans?

Comment: Each row could embed its own RecyclerView. However it depends on the type of data. You need to provide us with some more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for can be done with [`GridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager) itself, the only trick here is to use the [least common multiple (lcm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of your column counts per row as your total span count. Here is an easy example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    ...

    int spanCount = lcm(2, 1, 3, 8);
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, spanCount);
    layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            int numberOfColumns;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    numberOfColumns = 2;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    numberOfColumns = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numberOfColumns = 3;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    numberOfColumns = 8;
                    break;
                default:
                    numberOfColumns = spanCount;
            }
            return spanCount / numberOfColumns;
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    ...
}

public static int lcm(int... input) {
    int result = input[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) result = lcm(result, input[i]);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I just adapted a little bit the code for lcm method because this code raises StackOverflowError but the logic was what I expected.

Comment: @sylsau, you're welcome. Feel free to update my answer with your adapted lcm logic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you just need to create different Views and get them in the
 `if (holder instanceof ProfileAdapter.VideoViewHolder) {
                  } else {
                  }`
and throw the views inside the above method using 
`public int getItemViewType(int position) {
           }`